# Syntax Highlighter Not working in Angular Application

Tags: angular, syntax-highlighting

I have an Angular application and want to to display some Codes on the site. I added java script codes from Alexgorbatchev Syntax highlighter. It working good at site loading.  But not working after some input entered or changed on UI.

Will I have to call the SyntaxHighlighter.all() Method on NG changes?

Index.html

```
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
 <link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
 <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
 <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'></script>   

<script language='javascript'> 
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
 </script>
```

Page.html

```
<pre class="brush:java">{{vStr}}</pre>
```

Comment: I think it looks for elements when you make the call, which aren't there when the page is loaded because angular has to create them from the template.  Maybe use `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` in [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)?

Comment: I cant call the SyntaxHighlighter.all() method from the component. only we can call from html page

Comment: Then the element must be part of your page before the call I think and can't be part of your dynamic component templates, unless you do something like use a delay and hope that your components have created those elements by then...